# Monitoring HTTP traffic using tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump, tshark

To monitor HTTP traffic between a server and a web server, I'm currently using `tcpdump`. This works fine, but I'd like to get rid of some superfluous data in the output (I know about `tcpflow` and `wireshark`, but they're not readily available in my environment).

From the `tcpdump` man page:

> To print all IPv4 HTTP packets to and from port 80, i.e. print only packets that contain data, not, for example, SYN and FIN packets and ACK-only packets.
>
> `tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'`

This command

> sudo tcpdump -A 'src example.com and tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'

provides the following output:

> 19:44:03.529413 IP 192.0.32.10.http > 10.0.1.6.52369: Flags [P.], seq 918827135:918827862, ack 351213824, win 4316, options [nop,nop,TS val 4093273405 ecr 869959372], length 727
>
> **E.....@.......**
>   **....P..6.0.........D......**
>   __..e=3...__HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2009 18:35:22 GMT
>   Age: 7149
>   Content-Length: 438
>
> <HTML>
>   <HEAD>
>     <TITLE>Example Web Page</TITLE>
>   </HEAD> 
>   <body>
>   <p>You have reached this web page ...</p>
>   </BODY>
>   </HTML>

This is nearly perfect, except for the highlighted part. What is this, end -- more importantly -- how do I get rid of it? Maybe it's just a little tweak to the expression at the end of the command?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

tcpdump prints complete packets. "Garbage" you see are actually TCP package headers.

you can certainly massage the output with i.e. a perl script, but why not use tshark, the textual version of wireshark instead?

`tshark  'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'`

it takes the same arguments as tcpdump (same library) but since its an analyzer it can do deep packet inspection so you can refine your filters even more, i.e.

`tshark  'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
 -R'http.request.method == "GET" || http.request.method == "HEAD"'`

Comment: Thanks -- after trying out all the suggestions, tshark seems like the best tool for the job. I'm currently using "tshark -d tcp.port==8070,http -R 'http.request or http.response'". Now if only I could get tshark to "follow the tcp stream" just like wireshark can (This gets asked a lot, but I still haven't found the answer). "-V" displays info about the TCP and IP packets and so on, which I'm not interested in. But I guess I can remove that using a script.

Comment: You can also search for "GET" in a capture filter by matching the ASCII values for each character: `tcp port 80 and tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420`. I added a page to the Wireshark web site a while back that helps you create string matching capture filters: http://www.wireshark.org/tools/string-cf.html

Answer (score 18):

take a look at [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html) - it mighe be of some use for you.

as reference for others [httpry](http://dumpsterventures.com/jason/httpry/) [ server seems to be down now but i hope it's temporary ] and [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) are also useful for passive protocol analysis - first one just for http, second - for much more.

Comment: +1 for ngrep. Very useful tool.

Comment: ngrep and httpry look definitely useful, but ngrep is unaware of HTTP and AFAIK, httpry only works with HTTP headers and cannot display the payload data.

Comment: @sapporo - sure - ngrep is protocol agnostic, but you can add pcap filter "port 80" and get.. in [most cases] http traffic only.

Comment: Imo, ngrep is 100000x better than tcpdump

Answer (score 5):

Try [httpry](http://dumpsterventures.com/jason/httpry/) or [justniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/)

Justniffer works well on tcp packets reordering  retrasmissions and ip fragmentation

Comment: Thanks!  justniffer is what I was looking for (I think it's the only tool mentioned that is very simple *and* measures request duration).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a dumbed down tcpdump command line that stores everything in a pcap file for post process. Depending on what exactly you are looking at diagnosing tcpflow works great for putting communications back together in a coherent way for analysis.

Some other good information including some usages for httpry can be found at: http://taosecurity.blogspot.com/2008/06/logging-web-traffic-with-httpry.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the webserver you're using not produce logs? Surely that'd be a much better way to monitor HTTP traffic, there's a plethora of tools to analyse the data and any competent webserver should produce reliable logs.

Comment: Clearly. I imagine he already thought of that, though. Sometimes it's useful to monitor the actual data being sent between point A and point B.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available on the market designed specially for monitoring the HTTP Traffic. Fiddler2 (http://www.fiddler2.org) and [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com) are examples of such tools.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, both tools seem to work on Windows only. I hadn't mentioned it, but I'm loooking for something that works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your "issue" while using the TCPDUMP is that it is showing you the content of the header of the package.

If you still want to use TCPDUMP just remove the **-A**.  Doing this should remove that from the output.

```
sudo tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```